# Minimization of DFA

Tags: computer-science, automata, finite-automata

I have the following question

[image]

I have minimized the DFA as the following since the states can only be partitioned to [S0][S1 S2]
[image]

EDIT: Is my Minimization correct?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Your minimized DFA is correct; the language in question is the set of non-empty words over the alphabet $\{a,b\}^*$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Please see the update.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks.The rectangular state indicate the start state i think.Plus i think that the steps required to minimize would be writing the transition table.. then saying that only partition possible is [S0][S1 S2] .Hope thats enough.Its a 15 mark question including the general explanation.

Comment: @techno: I have to admit that I minimized it by eye. Not knowing exactly what minimization algorithm you’ve been taught, I can’t say how much explanation is really required. The wording suggests that you’re supposed to explain the general procedure for minimizing a DFA, not the details of this particular minimization.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I just followed this https://youtu.be/1GZOzTJOBuM?t=1m2s .Hope its the standard procedure.